# How to make php tree optgroup?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to setup a script from [here](https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-category-subcategory-tree-php-mysql/) I want the parent category in

`<optgroup>`or be **non-selectable and bold like '`<optgroup>`'**

---

Is it possible?

### SEE THE IMAGE HERE

[image]

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ORDER BY name ASC");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$sub_mark.$row['name'].'</option>';
            categoryTree($row['id'], $sub_mark.'---');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection and also consider using a better method than global to get variables in scope.

Comment: You'll need to echo your optgroup HTML like `'<optgroup label="' . $opt_grp_name . '>` and then close the group with a `</optgroup>`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `<optgroup>` tag is not selectable by definition. The bolding of the optgroup text is handled by your style sheet, which can also make other elements bold as well.  See the `:first` css selector and related selectors to bold the parent element.  As far as making it not selectable, if you are not using an optgroup for that, then you will need a javascript event listener to "fix" the inappropriate selection.  Its hard to give you a specific answer, because I do not know what CSS or HTML you are using based on the information in the question.